# Rails SQL Group by child, if its grandchildren all have the same attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scope, relational-algebra

I'm not entirely sure if this working correctly..

My goal is to.. :

```
# return members
# which have many courses
# which have many quizzes
# that are all complete.
```

In other words. If all the quizzes are complete from a certain course, I want to return only those members given just the `List` .

I made a stab at it. But I don't think my grouping is accurately accomplishing this. Would anyone know if this is the best way to approach this?

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base 

  has_many :members, through: :list_members, source: :member
  has_many :quizzes, through: :members
  has_many :courses, through: :quizzes

  has_many :completed_members, -> {
      includes(:courses, :quizzes)
      .select('courses.*')
      .group(['members.id', 'courses.id', 'quizzes.id'])
      .where.not(quizzes: {completed: [nil, false]})
      .references(:quizzes)
    }, through: :list_members, source: :member
```

Comment: Can you explain in what way your attempt produces an incorrect result?

Comment: @hoffm I'm not sure it's grouping by the course. I have the premonition that it's only ensuring that a member has only completed courses, not necessarily per course.